# Write to file with PowerShell not working

Tags: .net, powershell, writetofile

I'm trying to write to a file the result of:

```
$installedPrograms = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
```

And it doesn't work at all. I've tried using:

```
$installedPrograms >> "installedProgram.txt"
```

and

```
$installedPrograms | Out-File "installedPrograms.txt"
```

and

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "installedPrograms.txt"
1..10000|%
{
    $stream.WriteLine($installedPrograms)
}
$stream.Close();
```

None of the above worked...

Comment: So what *did* happen? Have you tried printing `$installedPrograms` to the console? Does it look correct?

Comment: Printing it to the console works fine, just not to a txtfile. I think it might be because of tabs in the string instead of spaces.

Comment: `$installedPrograms |Out-String |Out-File installedPrograms.txt`, but I'd suggest exporting to a csv file as [Itchydon's answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037056/712649)

Comment: @Narkael `"$installedPrograms"` is the console-equivalent of what you're trying to do. PowerShell has no idea how to convert the array to a meaningful string, that's why you end up with nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably better in a csv

```
$installedPrograms = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
$installedPrograms | export-csv installedPrograms.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked in the CSV File! But for some reason, doing `if ( $installedPrograms.Contains("NameOfTheProgram") ) { do something } else { dosomething else }` doesn't work. But I know that it contains the name of the program...

Comment: Try     `if($installedPrograms -match "NameOfTheProgram"){dosomething}`